# Буря: пыльная или пылевая?

Tags: выбор-слов, стилистика, согласование, словосочетания

Цитата ([источник](https://360tv.ru/news/nauka_i_tehnologiya/kosmicheskij-snimok-pomog-najti-15letnij-marsohod/)):

> Этот объект — роллер Opportunity, который спускался в Марсианскую
>   долину, когда **пыльная буря** прокатилась по поверхности чуть более
>   100 дней назад.

Словосочетание *пыльная буря* резануло слух, закралось подозрение на стилистическую ошибку. Но затем посмотрел примеры употреблений и так действительно пишут.

Хочется уточнить:

- *пыльная буря* и *пылевая буря* — одно и то же?
- насколько словосочетание *пыльная буря* правомерно с точки зрения аналогий (песчаная буря, но не **песочная буря*)?

Comment: Этот комментарий не по теме основного вопроса, но, как говорится, не могу пройти мимо. Построение фразы выдает неудачный перевод с иностранного языка. Речь идет о роллере Opportunity, а не о буре, значит время (**чуть более 100 дней назад**) следует связать с ним, а не с бурей: *спускался в Марсианскую долину чуть более 100 дней назад, когда пыльная буря прокатилась по поверхности.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словосочетание "пыльная буря" приводится как в словарной статье "буря", так и в статье "пыльный". 100 вхождений в Нацкопрусе.

> [БУРЯ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8F), -и; ж. 1. Сильный ветер большой разрушительной силы, сопровождаемый обычно дождём, снегом, градом. 
>   Б. поднялась, разыгралась, пронеслась, утихла. Бурей повалило деревья. 
>   Снежная б. Чёрная, **пыльная**, песчаная б. (сильный сухой ветер, выдувающий поверхностный слой почвы). * Буря мглою небо кроет, Вихри снежные крутя (Пушкин). 2. чего, какая. О глубоких социальных потрясениях в жизни общества. Социальные бури. Б. гражданской войны. 3. чего, какая. О сильных душевных переживаниях, волнениях. Душевная, сердечная б. Б. страстей, чувств, мыслей. 4. чего. Чрезвычайно сильное, бурное проявление чего-л. Б. восторгов. Б. рукоплесканий, оваций. ◊ Буря в стакане воды. О сильном волнении, горячем споре и т.п. по ничтожному поводу, из-за пустяков. Магнитная буря. Сильное возмущение магнитного поля Земли. <Буревой, -ая, -ое (1 зн.). Б-ые вихри.
>
> [ПЫЛЬНЫЙ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20), -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. 1. Состоящий из пыли; содержащий в себе пыль. П-ое облако. **П-ая буря**. // Отличающийся большим количеством пыли. П. город. П-ая улица. П-ая дорога. П. ковёр. П-ое лето. 2. только полн. Связанный с собиранием, улавливанием пыли. П-ые трубы. П-ая камера. П. подвал. 3. (обычно с отриц.). Разг. Трудный, тяжёлый (о работе). Работа у них не пыльная. ◊ Пыльным мешком ударенный. Шутл. О глуповатом человеке.

Слово *пылевой" гораздо менее употребимо.

> [пылевой](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9)
>   прил.
>   1) Соотносящийся по знач. с сущ.: пыль (1*1), связанный с ним.
>   2) Состоящий из пыли (1*1).
>   3) Имеющий вид пыли (1*1).

"Пылевая буря": только 21 вхождение в Нацкорпусе.

У обоих слов есть значение "состоящий из пыли". А вот слово ПЕСОЧНЫЙ не имеет значения "состоящий из песка", поэтому нет и "песочных бурь".